# JS - Move list text on mouse hover

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need some text to move to the right when the mouse hovers over it, here's what I have so far
JS:

```
$("#mainnav li").hover(function() {
$(this).css('padding-left', '50px');});
```

HTML:

```
<ul id="mainnav"> 
<li>hello</li>
<li>hello 1</li>
<li>hello 2</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to use **JQuery** you can do it like this, or you can do this with just **CSS** [`Fiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/4/)

```js
$('#mainnav li').hover(function() {
  $(this).css('padding-left', '30px');
}, function() {
  $(this).css('padding-left', '0');
});
```

```css
li {
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="mainnav"> 
  <li>hello</li>
  <li>hello 1</li>
  <li>hello 2</li>
</ul>
```